# If statements and variables

Tags: conditionals

I need some help understanding if statements.

How do I make the following pseudocode in LaTeX.

```
\newcommand{\@leader}{}
\newcommand{\leader}[1]{\renewcommand\@leader{#1}}

\newcommand{\donow}{
    \if \@leader == {}        %aka blank, null, empty
        this is the false     %do false
    \else   
        \@leader              %do leader
    \fi
}
```

Such that when a user adds the following to their document

```
\leader{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item this is an item
        \item this is also an item
    \end{itemize}
}

\donow

\leader{}

\donow
```

print the following

```
*This is an item

*this is also an item

this is the false
```

My only question about variables is, is the solution I have really the best way to do make variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test macro-to-macro using `\ifx`. That is, `\ifx<csA><csB><true>\else<false>\fi` will test whether the definition of `<csA>` matches that of `<csB>` and execute `<true>`, or `<false>` otherwise:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@emptymacro}{}% Used to test against an empty macro
\newcommand{\@something}{}
\newcommand{\something}[1]{\renewcommand\@something{#1}}

\newcommand{\donow}{%
  \ifx\@something\@emptymacro %aka blank, null, empty
    this is the false     %do false
  \else
    \@something           %do something
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\something{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
    \item this is also an item
  \end{itemize}
}

\donow

\something{}

\donow

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides similar checking mechanism:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@something}{}
\newcommand{\something}[1]{\renewcommand\@something{#1}}

\newcommand{\donow}{%
  \ifdefempty{\@something}{%aka blank, null, empty
    this is the false     %do false
  }{%
    \@something           %do something
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you Werner. I was traveling down the path of \newif and was stuck going in circles.

Answer (score 3):

The standard TeX code for given task is:

```
\def\something#1{\def\internal{#1}%
   \ifx\internal\empty the parameter is empty.\else it is nonempty.\fi
}
```

The problem of this code (above) is that the macro `\something` isn't expandable because it includes `\def` assignment. If you need expandable macro with the same test then you need to choose the token never used as the first token in the parameter (say `?` in our example) and you can write:

```
\def\something#1{\ifx?#1?the parameter is empty.\else it is nonempty.\fi}
```

If you don't know what token never occurs as first token of the parameter then you can use expandable `\detokenize` primitive from eTeX for example:

```
\if\penalty\detokenize{#1}\penalty the parameter empty.\else non-empty.\fi
```